# pandas - creating the ranking by occurrence only

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, ranking

I have a dataframe like  this one:

| user | item | oldRanking |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |

this oldRanking is the ranking of item per each user. It supposed to be complete number, but I had to use df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user','item']) to remove item that occurs multiple times and consume ranking place.

(for example, there was a row of user 0 item 0 with oldRanking 2, and 2 rows of user 1 item 1 with oldRanking 3 & 4)

I would like to create a new column, newRanking like this:

| user | item | oldRanking | newRanking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 3 |

which assign the ranking by its occurrence.
I tried df.groupby(['user','item'])['oldRanking'].rank(ascending=True) but it only returns 1.0 value for every single column.

how should I achieve newRanking column like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.groupby` does not nescessarly need an aggregation function, it can also be used to perform operation by subgroups of a dataframe. In this case you are interested in creating a cummulative count based on user groups:

```
df['newRanking']=df.groupby('user').cumcount()+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using `rank()`:

```py
df['newRanking'] = df.groupby('user')['item'].rank(method='min').convert_dtypes()
```

Output:

```
   user  item  oldRanking  newRanking
0     0     0           1           1
1     0     1           3           2
2     1     0           1           1
3     1     1           2           2
4     1     2           5           3
```